# Laravel use Hash as Validator

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i'm using `Hash::check()` to check current password with entered password. i use this if for check this action

```
$HashPassowrd = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

if( ! Hash::check( Input::get('currPassword') , $data->password ) )
{
   return Redirect::to('profile.update')
            ->withErrors('Current Password in Incorrect!');
}
```

how to use that as `validator` ? for example in this `rules`

```
$rules = array(
            'name'        => 'required|alpha',
            'family'      => 'required',
            'email'       => 'required|email',
            'currPassword'=> 'required',
            'password'    => 'required|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation'=>'required',
        );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add custom rule in to the validator:

```
Validator::extend('checkHashedPass', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    if( ! Hash::check( $value , $parameters[0] ) )
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Now you can use this custom rule as:

```
'currPassword' => 'required|checkHashedPass:' . Input::get('currPassword')
```

So, if the validation fails for this rule then you'll get error messages for this in your view and can access using `$errors->first('currPassword');` but you need to pass a custom error message for this custom rule you've created using:

```
$messages = array( 'currPassword.checkHashedPass' => 'Current Password failed!' );
```

So, during validation you have to pass the `$messages` array using:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);
```

Check [custom validation rules](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules) on the documentation.

Comment: What if the user's password includes a pipe or a colon?

Answer (score 3):

You also can use a closure validation rule:

```
    [
        'currPassword' => function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if (! Hash::check($value, $this->user()->password)) {
                $fail('Your current password doesnt match');
            }
        },
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel 6.x a password validation rule is added that will do the above for you.

Check [its documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-password)

simply add this rule to your validation rules :

> 'password' => 'password:api'

where api is the **authentication guard**